# Pattern matching in a zsh conditional expression

Tags: regular-expression, zsh, wildcards, string, test

I am having trouble with pattern matching in zsh's hook function `precmd`. I have the following:

```
precmd(){
   local x='test'
   if [ $x = '*test*' ]; then
      echo 'hello'
   fi
}
```

which does not print hello ever. I've tested this code with a normal `zsh test.zsh` that works fine, and I've tried w/o the regex in `precmd` and got things to print out fine as well. Any clue as to why this isn't working as expected?

```
$ zsh --version
zsh 4.3.11 RHEL
```

Comment: hook functions: `http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html` and regex is a bit of a misnomer, actually a globbing pattern: `http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation`

Comment: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Conditional-Expressions.html see edit above as well.

Comment: the content in the function works outside of that function as stated in the Q, so it seems like I am using their pattern matching correctly. this just doesn't work properly when placed in the precmd function

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`[ $x = '*test*' ]` tests whether the string resulting from expanding `$x`, which is `text`, is equal to the string resulting from expanding `'*test*'`, which is `*text*`.

To test whether the value of the variable `x` matches the *pattern* `*test*`, you need to use the `=` or `==` operator of [zsh conditional expressions](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Conditional-Expressions.html#Conditional-Expressions), which are written within [double brackets](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#index-_005b_005b) `[[ … ]]`. Furthermore special characters in the pattern must be unquoted, otherwise they stand for themselves. Thus:

```
if [[ $x == *test* ]]; then …
```

The syntax of conditional expressions is similar to the syntax of expressions that you can use within single brackets `[ … ]`, but not identical. `[` is parsed like an ordinary command; in fact, it's a built-in command with a one-character name, which is identical to the [`test` builtin](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-test) except that `[` requires an additional argument at the end which must be `]`. `[[ … ]]` is a distinct grammatical construct, which allows it to have shell special characters inside. `[ $x = *test* ]` would expand `*test*` to the list of matching file names (globbing) and the `test` builtin would end up parsing the result of that. `[[ $x = *test* ]]` parses `*test*` as part of conditional expression parsing which does not invoke globbing.

Comment: Or use the standard `case $x in (*test*) ... ;esac` syntax.

Comment: Why does `[[ "$x" == "{*, *}" ]]` never return true ? Trying to match `{0, 1}` for example

Comment: @minseong The `*` are in quotes, so only `{*, *}` matches. You need e.g. `[[ "$x" == {*', '*} ]]` or `[[ "$x" == {*,\ *} ]]` (braces don't need to be quoted in a glob pattern). Those also match e.g. `{0, 1, 2}` and `{{{{{, }` so maybe you want something like `shopt -s extglob; [[ "$x" == {+([0-9]),\ +([0-9])} ]]` or `[[ "$x" =~ {[0-9]+,\ [0-9]+} ]]` instead.

Answer (score 10):

`*test*` is not a valid regex pattern.  The `*` is a repetition operator and needs something to repeat.  It's very likely you want `.*test.*`, although that isn't necessary with regex since it is not anchored by default.  You could just look for `test`

However you cannot match regex patterns with the `=` operator, you need `=~`.

```
precmd () {
   local x=test
   if [[ $x =~ test ]]; then
      echo 'hello'
   fi
}
```

Comment: Why switch to regexp matching with `=~`? You can keep the wildcard syntax and the `=` operator. The only thing that needs to change is to use `[[` instead of `[`.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil': I'm no zsh expert and OP said they wanted regex.

Comment: That's more a bash (3.2+) answer. In zsh, you can quote the regexps, and generally want to if they contain special characters. Use `[[ $x =~ '.*test.*' ]]` or `[ "$x" '=~' '.*test.*' ]` or `[[ $x = *test* ]]` (no quote there), or `[[ $x =~ test ]]`